# iOS Google Analytics missing first UIViewController

Tags: ios6, google-analytics

BLUF: Google Analytics iOS v2 beta 4 misses tracking my first `UIViewController` that is loaded while hitting successfully on subsequent `UIViewControllers` (subclassed with `GAITrackedViewController`)

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Optional: automatically send uncaught exceptions to Google Analytics.
    [GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
    // Optional: set Google Analytics dispatch interval to e.g. 20 seconds.
    [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 0;
    // Optional: set debug to YES for extra debugging information.
    [GAI sharedInstance].debug = YES;
    // Create tracker instance.
    [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-########-1"];    // id<GAITracker> tracker = 

    return YES;
}
```

MainViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad");
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.trackedViewName = @"First Screen";
    //[[GAI sharedInstance] dispatch];
    ...
}
```

I do not call dispatch manually on the working `UIViewController`'s, and I have tried both calling and not calling on the non-working.  But it is a mystery.  No logs are generated if I don't call it manually.  When I do call dispatch manually I receive the following:

> GoogleAnalytics 2.0b4 -[GAIDispatcher initiateDispatch:retryNumber:]
>   (GAIDispatcher.m:481) DEBUG: No pending hits.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out that you should **really** make sure that if you override any methods, you should make sure to call super on them as well...

I had written my own `viewDidAppear` method but had not called `[super viewDidAppear:animated];`.  I guess that is where GoogleAnalytics does their magic.  Hopefully this will help someone else *not* do this as well.

Answer (score 2):

in my Case , I did call super method , but it did not work at some pages .
and I just change the order and let GA before the super method , It did work now .

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.screenName = @"mainMenu";
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Contrary to Shu Zhang answer: super should be called first and then you should add other code: 

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.screenName = @"YourViewControllerName";
    //your implementation here
}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    ///your implementation here...
}
```